# Aligning y-axis label with middle of subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I'm working with Matplotlib and have a large number of 1D heatmaps, each with their own label. However, the labels are misaligned with the plots and I cannot figure out to get this to work automatically.

Here's an MWE

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.random.rand(10, 1000)
dogs = ["woof", "bark", "bowwow"]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(10)
for i in range(10):
    axs[i].scatter(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), np.linspace(0,1,1000)*0, 2000,
                     c=data[i, :], marker="|", cmap='inferno')
    axs[i].set_frame_on(False)
    axs[i].set_yticklabels([])
    axs[i].set_xticklabels([])
    axs[i].set_xticks([])
    axs[i].set_yticks([])
    axs[i].set_ylabel(dogs[i%3], rotation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

I experimented with

```
    axs[i].yaxis.set_label_coords(x, y)
```

for various values of x and y, and nothing seems to work. I would prefer to have it align automatically, with the bottom of the text corresponding to the bottom of the individual plot.

Attached is an image showcasing the alignment issue.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qxUB.png)

Comment: @tdy Updated with MWE

Comment: `axs[i].set_ylabel(dogs[i%3], rotation='horizontal', verticalalignment='center')`

Answer (score 0):

You could create your heatmaps via seaborn, and use `yticklabels=[label_name]` to set the labels. Rotating the labels to 0 degrees should have them nicely aligned.  Note that the data is expected to have a shape of `1xN`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

labels = ['Alkaid', 'Mizar', 'Alioth', 'Megrez', 'Phecda', 'Merak', 'Dubhe']
nrows = len(labels)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, figsize=(10, 5))

for ax_i, data_i, label_i in zip(axs, np.random.randn(nrows, 1, 100).cumsum(axis=2), labels):
    sns.heatmap(data=data_i, xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[label_i], cmap='inferno', cbar=False, ax=ax_i)
    ax_i.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=0, labelsize=22, length=0) # length means length of the tick mark
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: vertical grid of heatmaps with labels]

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around, I found that

```
axs[0].set_ylabel("Pseudotime", fontsize=12, rotation='horizontal', ha='right', va='center')
```

is sufficient for aligning the y-labels.

Comment: Wouldn't `axs[i].set_yticks([0], [dogs[i%3]], fontsize=12)` be enough?